# alternatedocroot_n in payara/glassfish not working

Tags: java, glassfish, virtualhost, payara

My application creates an XML sitemap file for my website and saves it in a different folder of the server. I want search bots to access this file.

I had defined a docbase in tomcat server.xml file and bots were able to access the file. I have changed the web server to Payara. I have created a `alternatedocroot_1` property with the `value from=/sm/* dir=/home/pc/images` (even setting dir to dir=/home/pc/images/sm` doesn't work) in the virtual host file for the application. When I try to access the sitemap, payara displays 404 error. (I had restarted the server)

The file is stored in the folder named `sm` in `/home/pc/images`.
How to fix this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your **glassfish-web.xml** should look like this to make it work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/sm/* dir=/home/pc/images" />
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Comment: glassfish-web.xml of my project looks exactly the same